# Will mysql_fetch_row ever face connection errors?

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

[**mysql_fetch_row**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) returns an array when there are results, or `false` when there are no more rows.

But what's the expected behavior when a connection-related error occured while running the command?

Or rather, I should ask... **Will the function `mysql_fetch_row` ever require a database connection?**

On my box, I can actually close the connection ([`mysql_close`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php)) and still fetch rows perfectly. However I can't find any documentation stating that this behavior is the norm, or if it's even expected.

Comment: A connection error would come from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: This (the connection going away in that specific moment after one was successfully established previously) sounds like a really, really rare edge case. Not sure whether it's worth dealing with in the first place?

Comment: I've always assumed the mysql resource is stored locally after you run the query.  It seems inefficient to pull rows from a remote server one at a time.

Comment: look at  what `mysql_error()` returns. BUT, the mysql_* function set has been deprecated.  You would do better to use either mysqli_* functions or pdo_* functions.

Comment: I notice nobody has mentioned yet that the mysql_* functions are deprecated. Let me correct this by saying: mysql_* is deprecated. You should move to PDO instead.

Comment: Let me repeat this just in case the previous comment isn't displayed properly: mysql_* is deprecated.

Comment: @SamDufel, on my setup I can actually run `mysql_close` before I run `mysql_fetch_row` and I have no errors. But, are you saying that this is portable? Is it *official* that we can do `mysql_close` before we do `mysql_fetch_row`?

Comment: @Pekka웃, yes but I'm fixing some old code and thus require knowing how these functions work. Rewriting the whole thing would not be ideal.

Comment: @Pacerier I was kidding in light of no less than *four* comments making the same tired point. (still, the advice isn't wrong, of course.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of "query" functions:

- Your normal [`mysql_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) which everyone uses
- And the largely unnoticed [`mysql_unbuffered_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-unbuffered-query.php)

Now if you use the `mysql_query` the complete result set is stored on the client. So once `mysql_query` returns there is no server communication necessary. You can get the size of the result set and use `mysql_seek`. Internally the function [`mysql_store_result`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-store-result.html) is used and if the server dies while the results are fetched on the client your `mysql_query` calls fails. But if the result set is completely stored on the client `mysql_fetch_row` won't fail if the server dies while you are fetching them.

If you use `mysql_unbuffered_query` you need to have a valid link to the, because the result set is not stored on the client - instead each row is fetched when you call `mysql_fetch_row`. So if the link "dies" the next call to `mysql_fetch_row` will fail. The C-function [`mysql_use_result`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-use-result.html) is used in the "unbuffered" call.

I have created a [simple PHP-script](http://codepad.org/bncGpPJQ) to test this (too big to paste).

To quote the manual of the [`mysql_fetch_row`-function of the mysql C-Library](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-fetch-row.html):

> Retrieves the next row of a result set. When used after mysql_store_result(), mysql_fetch_row() returns NULL when there are no more rows to retrieve. When used after mysql_use_result(), mysql_fetch_row() returns NULL when there are no more rows to retrieve or if an error occurred.

This states implicit:

- If `mysql_store_result` (buffered normal query) is used, then `mysql_fetch_row` returns only null if there are no more rows to fetch
- If `mysql_use_result` (unbuffered query) is used, then `mysql_fetch_row` returns null if there are no more rows **or** if there was an error fetching the next row from the server.

There is no reference to any platform specific behaviour, so I think this applies to all platforms. Of course we would have to dig into the source code of those functions to be certain.

Regarding the behaviour in case of an error: on the PHP-side `mysql_fetch_result` will return false if a fetch of an unbuffered result set fails (or if there are no more rows). The `mysql_*`-functions don't throw exceptions, but in case of a failure a warning is emitted - in my script it says `Warning: mysql_fetch_row(): 8 is not a valid MySQL result resource in ...`. So if you want to check for an error you would have to do something like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
   // do stuff
}

if(mysql_errno($dbhandle) !== 0) {
    echo "there was an error: ", mysql_error($dbhandle), PHP_EOL;
}
```

If you want to write really defensive code, you'd have to do that regardless of which query-function you are using.

By the way: this defensive code won't work if the mysql-connection is closed with `mysql_close`, since the handles are now closed and `mysql_errno` returns false (plus emits a warning).

Comment: So you are saying that regardless of platform, mysql_fetch_row-on-mysql_query will be connectionless? So assuming we are now using mysql_unbuffered_query, what is the defined behavior for connection failing? Is it throw exception or return false?

Comment: @Pacerier: thank you for your response. I have expanded my answer a bit to answer your questions. In short: According to the MySQL-manual the fetch on `mysql_query`-resultsets won't fail. And no, no exception is thrown. You would have to check the return value of `mysql_errno` to be sure. But if you write really defensive code you would have to do that any way.

Comment: Ok to round up, so you are saying we got to check `mysql_errno` only if we are using `mysql_unbuffered_query` because fetching rows after a normal `mysql_query` would **never** give us problems right?

Comment: I would say it's very unlikely that `mysql_fetch_row` fails if the whole result set is fully fetched. If you check the result of `mysql_query` you should be on the safe side.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look into mysql_error

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

The mysql_* functions have been depreciated, you should consider using PDO or Mysqli.

Comment: On my side I can close the connection (mysql_close) and still fetch rows perfectly.  Does mysql_fetch_row even need a db connection?

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to check for connection errors etc, use [mysql_errno](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-errno.php), but you really shouldn't be using the mysql library any more as it's been deprecated; move on to MySQLi or PDO

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_row() calls mysql_query() which returns an error if there is an error.

Comment: That's not true. At least on my side, I cannot mysql_query after closing the connection. **But I can still mysql_fetch_row.**

Comment: Are you sure? Maybe you can add some example code to your question?!

Comment: Of course I'm sure... I don't usually forget things that happen just 3 minutes ago.

Comment: I closed the connection with a single statement: `mysql_close();`

Answer (score 0):

You must distinguish between the return value of `mysql_query` and the return value of `mysql_fetch_row`. If you want to check for connection related errors, you first check the return value of

```
$result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());
```

and if you check for end of result set, you check the return value of `mysql_fetch_row`.